# angularjs ng-repeat callback function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

is there a way to have a callback issued for each repetition of an ng-repeat. I have a collection which is filtered, and would need to modify the text dynamically every time an item is shown. If not possible, are there any workarounds?

```
<span ng-repeat="item in items|myfilter">
    <div nonexisting-ng-repeat-callback="getTextFromServer({{item.id}})"></div>
</span>
```

**Update:**

When I try the following:

```
<span ng-repeat="item in items|myfilter">
    <div ng-style="{{item.style}}" ng-init="getTextFromServer(item)"></div>
</span>
```

with this in the $scope

```
$scope.getColor = function (item) {
    var data = item.percentageComplete;
    if (data == 100) {
        return {
            color: "green"
        };
    } else {
        return {
            color: "orange"
        };
    }
};

$scope.getTextFromServer = function (item) {
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/mypage',
            params : {"uri" : item.Url +"&Result=Percentage"}
        }).
        success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            item.percentageComplete = data;
            item.style = $scope.getColor(item);
        }).
        error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log(data + " - " + status);
            item.percentageComplete = undefined;
            item.style = $scope.getColor(item);
        });
};
```

the getTextFromServer is called, but the ng-style is not updated when the http call returns.

Regards,
Leen

Comment: You should try to find a solution where you have that data supplied with `items`. What you're doing is very impractical (dozens of network requests, DOM rendering-based callbacks...)

Comment: why dont you put a filter on individual items also

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`ng-init`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angInit) or [`ng-show`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angShow) directive:

```
<span ng-repeat="item in items|myfilter">
    <div ng-init="getTextFromServer({{item.id}})"></div>
</span>
```

or

```
<span ng-repeat="item in items|myfilter">
    <div ng-show="condition"></div>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ngInit](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angInit) directive:

```
<span ng-repeat="item in items|myfilter">
    <div ng-init="getTextFromServer({{item.id}})"></div>
</span>
```

Comment: ng-init is called the first time, any change in `items` will break everything

Comment: It does not work, the console.log() isn't called after the splice. So if you modify your item into your ng-init, it won't be called the second time

Comment: But in question: '...and would need to modify the text dynamically every time an item is shown.'. So it is not need to do something when item is removed.

Comment: I think this is not correct usage of filters. Filter should only get some input data and return some output data without modifying passed input data.

Comment: I agree, using filters that way is not a good idea (but still better than ng-init, at least, it does the job). What about ng-bind ? http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/3278/ . BTW, in that case, Promises are a good solution. +1

Comment: It seems that promises works fine only if you bind itself directly but not throught function return value.

Comment: If you use $resource from a directive, and apply the style from this directive, it should work